# Load Custom Settings from DB at boot time.

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, migration

I am currently working on an app in Laravel 4, for which I am trying to load a few custom settings (stored in the database) at boot time via a Service Provider, in this case a Theme Version.

```
<?php 

namespace Blah\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Blah\Repositories\SettingRepositoryInterface;
use Blah\Repositories\EloquentSettingRepository;
use \App;
use \View;

class SettingRepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('SettingRepositoryInterface', 'Blah\\Repositories\\EloquentSettingRepository');
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->settings = App::make('SettingRepositoryInterface');
        $this->theme();
    }

    public function theme() 
    {
        $version = $this->settings->load('active_theme');
        $path = app_path() . '/views/' . $version;
        View::addNameSpace('theme',$path);    
    }
}
```

It all works well, however I find that after I have rolled back migrations, I am unable to migrate again.

It seems that the Service Provider code is executed for some reason when performing the migration, as I get an SQL error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation     \"settings\" does not exist\nLINE 1: select * from \"settings\" where \"setting_name\" = $1 limit 1\n                      ^ (SQL: select * from \"settings\" where \"setting_name\" = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array (\n  0 => 'active_theme',\n))","file":"\/Users\/charlduplessis\/design\/projects\/blah\/_dev\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php","line":556}}
```

I don't understand why Service Providers have any effect on migrations.

Is it wrong of me to access the database within my Service Provider boot() (or in my case via a Repository class)?

If so, what would be the most elegant way of loading from the db to customise app behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, looks like these service providers are being registered and booting in the bootstrap, so you're hitting the database before they exist.

You can easily just not use a service provider, and dot his with just a regular old class.

Comment: Hi Phil! Seen your name around the Laravel circles... great to get your response. I asked Taylor about the most elegant way to load custom settings from the DB at boot time (on a very limited Twitter feed), and he seemed to think using a Service Provider is ok. Truth is, I'm not set on using a Service Provider, I just want to do it the right way. So, if this was your app, and you wanted some way of controlling the theme dynamically (hence storing something in the DB), how would you load it, use it to set the namespace for your views and then render the page?

Comment: Your service provider is just a class which loads some data. Making it into a service provider means it registers, and has boot logic early on, which is causing you trouble it seems. Just make a class, add a method which loads the data, then pass that class around if you need to. The IoC will help you with that.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response Phil, I've been moving flat. Ok I've moved the DB logic out of the Service Provider into a separate class. Final question: Is there a way I can now use this class to load custom settings once without putting it in every controller?

Comment: Create a base controller and assign the instance to a property?

Comment: @Charl, I have a similar requirement in 2015! Can you share the class you have written and/or the BaseController? I'm writing a set of classes to process payments and the related config needs to be loaded from DB (site manager should be able to manage these settings)